# Problemas con nextElementSibling a la hora de calcular un total - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy intentado realizar una multiplicacion entre cantidad y precio, para sacar su total, sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error a la hora de hacerlo: `TypeError: $(...).nextElementSibling is not a function`, no se de que forma podria modificarlo de tal forma que sea aceptable, comparto mi codigo:

**form**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="quantity">
    <input type="text" id="price">
    <input type="text" class="result">
</form>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $('#quantity, #price').keyup(function(){
        var cant = parseFloat(this.nextElementSibling('#quantity').val()) || 0;
        var price = parseFloat(this.nextElementSibling('#price').val()) || 0;
        var result = cant * price
        this.nextElementSibling('.result').val(result);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías buscar los elementos usando `$('selector')` de jquery, así:

```js
$('#quantity, #price').keyup(function() {
  var cant = parseFloat($('#quantity').val()) || 0;
  var price = parseFloat($('#price').val()) || 0;
  var result = cant * price
  $('.result').val(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="quantity"><br>
  <input type="text" id="price"><br>
  <input type="text" class="result">
</form>
```

`nextElementSibling` funcionaria si haces algo como `document.getElementById("quantity").nextElementSibling` pero te seleccionaría el *hermano* de `quantity`, que es `price` y no creo que sea muy práctico usarlo así, incluso, en el caso del código que pegué el hermano sería `<br>`.

Si quieres multiplicar ítems agregados dinamicamente, puedes usar clases en lugar de ids:

```js
$('.multi').keyup(function() {

  var precio = [];
  var cantidad = [];

  $('.precio').each(function(i, obj) {
    precio.push(+obj.value);
  });

  $('.cantidad').each(function(i, obj) {
    cantidad.push(+obj.value);
  });

  var resultado = 0;

  precio.map((o, i) => {
    resultado += o * cantidad[i];
  });

  $("#result").val(resultado);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="multi precio"> precio<br>
  <input type="text" class="multi cantidad"> cantidad<br><br>
  <input type="text" class="multi precio"> precio<br>
  <input type="text" class="multi cantidad">cantidad<br><br>
  <input type="text" class="multi precio"> precio<br>
  <input type="text" class="multi cantidad">cantidad<br><br>
  <input type="text" class="multi precio"> precio<br>
  <input type="text" class="multi cantidad">cantidad<br><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="result">resultado
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar Emeeus! Fijate q inicialmente asi lo tenia, sucede que estoy replicando el formulario para cada item de compra, pero no estoy seguro como hacer para que de forma dinamica se le asigne un id a cada item, ya que al hacerlo de la forma en como me la sugieres, solo lo hace en un solo item, tienes alguna idea de como se podria asignar de forma automatica un id? o que cada calculo sea aplicable a cada item

Comment: Y de eso forma Emeeus, como podria identificar cual es precio y cual es cantidad, para realizar la multiplicacion?

Comment: Edite la pregunta agregando como podria, ser, pero no se si es correcto Emeeus?

Comment: Exactamente, precio * cantidad, de cada item en este caso

Comment: @HectorHernandez me parece que necesitas esto https://jsfiddle.net/6oc1awyp/

Comment: Tremendo Emeeus!! Es exactamente lo que necesito! =D Solo una consulta mas, como podria hacer para que cada item, tengo como su resultado individual, es decir, que un PEPSI cuesta $0.50 y el clientes lleva 2, seria $1.00 en ese item, y q al mismo tiempo el resultado global se mantenga, es decir lo mismo pero calcular tambien el individual de cada item

Comment: Porque lo implemente a mis campos dinamicos, cada uno tiempo un campo de total_inidividual, pero el resultado solo me lo muestra en el campo de resultado del primer item, los demas quedan vacios

Comment: @HectorHernandez Necesitas subtotales no? Y después sumar los subtotales para conformar el total

Comment: Exactamente Emeeus, basicamente cada calculo de cada item seria un subtotal, y la suma de los subtotales seria el total =D

Comment: @HectorHernandez Aquí con subtotales https://jsfiddle.net/g3ujv45f/ si esto se vuelve mas complicado quizá te convine encararlo de otra manera, pero para empezar creo que está bien.

Comment: Te agradezco muchisimo Emeeus!!! Definitivamente me has salvado la vida! Ahorita te doy ese check! =D y Mil gracias sobre todo! Por toda tu amabilidad y tiempo!

Comment: De nada @HectorHernandez

Comment: Saludos Emmeus, ¿Podrias editar tu respuesta y agregar el contenido del ultimo jsfiddle a la respuesta? Tengo una pregunta que tiene que ver con esta, y redireccionare la respuesta que me distes a este post, de esta forma, usuarios que tengan un problema similar, terminaran dando con tu respuesta, saludos!